Does anyone know why my cPanel has migrated and now the main domain has changed to a dummy domain? And how I fix this?
I received an email that my 'migration for cPanel web hosting is now complete'. But the services migrated are a random dummy domain address.
Now my website isn't working and the main domain is the dummy address.
It seems to be because of this: Linux Hosting customers will be migrated from CloudLinux 6 to CloudLinux 8.
I can't see where or how to change this to get my website working again. My domain is listed in my hosting account as 'Active', but when I go to my website it asks me to log in to the cPanel to 'launch this site'.
Does anyone know how to fix this/how this error may have occurred? My hosting platform is Tsohost and I have a Wordpress site.
I've been able to login to the cPanel dashboard which lists my domain under the dummy domain. The dummy domain is labelled as 'Main Domain'.
Next to this, it says Public HTML. I'm not familiar with cPanel in the slightest, so I'm not sure how to navigate it and don't want to make the issue worse.

You'll need to contact your host but as you're using tsohost, I wish you good luck with that sir.

Just contact your Hosting service provider. If your hosting is shared, you may not have WHM access to your Cpanel.
Suppose you have website files inside the public_html folder and an Addon domain on your hosting plan. In that case, you can easily add your domain after clicking on the Addon domain from the Cpanel dashboard and entering your domain name. Below this, it will ask you to enter the domain root path.
Just enter the path of your website files from public_html.
You can also check this guide for Cpanel Addon Domains.
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053267473-How-to-create-an-Addon-Domain
Please contact your hosting provider if you can't find your files inside the public_html folder or the file manager.
OR if you have your files in the file manager & you don't have an option of Addon Domains, ask them to change the dummy domain with your Main domain (website domain) & make sure your files are located inside the public_html folder.
Just let me know if you need any help regarding this.
